# Android JNI: SIGSEGV on CallObjectMethod

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface, jnienv

I am trying to call method of custom Java type, but receiving  SIGSEGV signal.

Here is the Java Code

```
package com.example.JniApi;
public class JniApi {   
    public void test()
    {
        MyType obj = new MyType();
        nativePrintMyTypeMsg(obj);
    }
    public static native void nativePrintMyTypeMsg(MyType obj);
}

public class MyType {
    public void printMsg()
    {
        android.util.Log.d("TestJni", "From Java");
    }
}
```

And here is the native code

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_example_JniApi_JniApi_nativePrintMyTypeMsg
(JNIEnv *env , jclass, jobject myObj)
{
    jclass myTypeClass = env->GetObjectClass(myObj);
    jmethodID printMsgMethodId = env->GetMethodID(myTypeClass,"printMsg", "()V");
    for(size_t i = 0; i < 1000; ++i){
        env->CallObjectMethod(myObj, printMsgMethodId);
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: You must provide complete error checking in your JNI code. Every JNI API can fail, and you have to check them yourself, with `ExceptionCheck()` for example; also, `GetMethodID()` can return zero, which you also aren't checking. Do that and post the results.

Comment: I have changed the native code and added checks for zero and `ExceptionCheck()` as well, but again there is SIGSEGV on `CallObjectMethod`

Comment: And is `printMsgMethodId` non-zero?

Comment: `env, myObj, printMsgMethodId`: all of them are non-zero

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just from memory and looking at your snippet, there are 2 things I'd like to point out:

```
(JNIEnv *env , jclass, jobject myObj)
```

This signature looks a bit odd with the second parameter missing a parameter object. For sanity please change it to

```
(JNIEnv *env , jclass jclazz, jobject myObj)
```

Next and probably more important, the method `printMsg()` in your `MyType`-class is actually returning `void`. To invoke a void-method via JNI, you need to call it via `CallVoidMethod` instead. For more information, please check the [JNI Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#wp16656)

Comment: `CallVoidMethod` helped. Thanks

Comment: Leaving off the name of an unused parameter is pretty common for avoiding warnings, and causes no problems